# Does the hypergeometric distribution follow a Bernoulli process?

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, hypergeometric-distribution, bernoulli-process

There is a comment in an online resource that I need help understanding:

> In a Bernoulli process, given that there are M successes among N trials, the number X
> of successes among the first n trials has a Hypergeometric(N; M; n) distribution. source:  [https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma217/distributions2.pdf](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/ma217/distributions2.pdf)

**Problem:**  I am confused because my understanding is that the Bernoulli process requires repeated independent Bernoulli trials with FIXED probability p; however, sampling from a hypergeometric distribution are not independent, since a given sampling alters the probability of subsequent samplings.  I must be missing something or reading it incorrectly.

**Question:**  How or why does Bernoulli process come into play for hypergeometric distributions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The steps in the comment that prompted the question could be described a little more clearly as follows:

1. There was, in the past, a Bernoulli process that generated $M$
   successes in $N$ trials.
2. Now, we take a subset of the $N$ trials, in this case, the first $n$ of them, and see how many of them are successes ($X$).
3. $X$ has a Hypergeometric distribution with parameters $(N,M,n)$.

The reason the Bernoulli nature of the process is important is that it guarantees the locations of the $M$ successes among the $N$ trials are completely random; all possible permutations of the individual successes and failures are equally likely. Without this, you can't get to the Hypergeometric for the number of successes in the first $n$ trials. If you randomly sampled $n$ of the results you would end up with a Hypergeometric variate, even without the initial process being Bernoulli, but that's not what's happening here. Imagine a generating process that first produced $M$ successes and then produced $N−M$ failures; the number of successes in the first $n$ trials would not be Hypergeometric.

Comment: in a different setup for a hypergeometric distribution in which one draws n marbles while blindfolded from an urn with M blue and N-M red marbles, we do not seem to need the Bernoulli process (similar to your comment about "randomly sampled n of the results").  Therefore, it seems to me that the Bernoulli process is not truly "fundamental" to the hypergeometric distribution in the way it is for the binomial, geometric, and negative binomial? The latter 3 naturally arise from repeated Bernoulli trials but the former does not (even if it may depend on it initially). Is this fair?

Comment: @SnehalPatel - The keys to the Hypergeometric are finite population size, sampling without replacement, and an equal probability on any draw of selecting any of the remaining elements in the population.  Since we are sampling without replacement, the probability changes after every sample.   In this case, however, the Bernoulli requirement is there because of how we selected the population in the first place and the fact that we are sampling the first $n$ elements selected for that population.  Other constructions, such as the urn model, don't require that initial Bernoulli sampling step.